# unable to compile pacman(ArchLinux package manager) in ubuntu

Tags: archlinux, pacman-package-manager

I have tried to do the Offline Installation as described in the ArchLinux wiki, but it did not worked out as i have mentioned in the thread https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/12588344. Hence i have planned to compile the pacman in a machine which has internet connection and then download the packages using the compiled pacman binary and then transfer it to offline ArchLinux Machine.

While i tried to compile the pacman in Ubuntu-11.10 machine i got the following errors

```
$ make # after ./autogen.sh && ./configure
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/talespin/archlinux/pacman'
Making all in lib/libalpm
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/talespin/archlinux/pacman/lib/libalpm'
Making all in po
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/talespin/archlinux/pacman/lib/libalpm/po'
test ! -f ./libalpm.pot || \
      test -z "ca.gmo cs.gmo da.gmo de.gmo el.gmo en_GB.gmo es.gmo fi.gmo fr.gmo hu.gmo it.gmo kk.gmo lt.gmo nb.gmo pl.gmo pt.gmo pt_BR.gmo ro.gmo ru.gmo sk.gmo sr.gmo sr@latin.gmo sv.gmo tr.gmo uk.gmo zh_CN.gmo zh_TW.gmo" || make ca.gmo cs.gmo da.gmo de.gmo el.gmo en_GB.gmo es.gmo fi.gmo fr.gmo hu.gmo it.gmo kk.gmo lt.gmo nb.gmo pl.gmo pt.gmo pt_BR.gmo ro.gmo ru.gmo sk.gmo sr.gmo sr@latin.gmo sv.gmo tr.gmo uk.gmo zh_CN.gmo zh_TW.gmo
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/talespin/archlinux/pacman/lib/libalpm/po'
: --update  --lang=ca ca.po libalpm.pot
rm -f ca.gmo && : -c --statistics --verbose -o ca.gmo ca.po
mv: cannot stat `t-ca.gmo': No such file or directory
make[4]: *** [ca.gmo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/talespin/archlinux/pacman/lib/libalpm/po'
make[3]: *** [stamp-po] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/talespin/archlinux/pacman/lib/libalpm/po'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/talespin/archlinux/pacman/lib/libalpm'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/talespin/archlinux/pacman'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have cloned the source from git://projects.archlinux.org/pacman.git and tried compiling with the commit e6f72c61a098b52ea29e54b8eb4739a2ff81e6b0 and its parents(until commit ae25167bcd592186749b79ea31b10fb78ed9fb2d) with no success.

Comment: Do you have [libarchive](http://code.google.com/p/libarchive/) and [librcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) installed as installation instructions say?

Comment: yes, There are 3 variants of curl library available for ubuntu-11.10. I am using libcurl4-gnutls-dev. But still no luck. By the way i think you have made a typo on librcurl, it should be libcurl.

Comment: yep, libcurl it is. Anyway, the error message seems to be: `mv: cannot stat 't-ca.gmo': No such file or directory`. Is that `t-ca.gmo` stuff in place? It seems `ca-gmo` is a real name, but `t-ca.gmo`?

Comment: cd in to the dir **pacman/lib/libalpm/po** and running dry make (make -n) displays command mv t-${lang}.gmo. seems lang variable set to 'ca'. Any idea on what are the **.gmo** files

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.archlinux.org/pacman/translation-help.html) helps. Maybe change the variable to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved as explained in the mailing list http://mailman.archlinux.org/pipermail/pacman-dev/2012-March/015341.html

Used the git commit e6f72c61a098b52ea29e54b8eb4739a2ff81e6b0in

repo git://projects.archlinux.org/pacman.git

1) $ git clean -xfd; ./autogen.sh && ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var \

--enable-git-version --enable-debug --without-gpgme

2) cd lib/libalpm

3) In the Makefile replace line

LIBS = -lssl -larchive -lm

with
LIBS = -lssl -larchive -lm -lcrypto

4) cd ../../ && make